# Remote Database Retrieval CronJob

Tags: mysql, macos, shell, cron, remote-access

I'd like to set up a cronjob which downloads a remote database (nightly) via SSH and creates the database locally (in OSX) using MySql.

Any recommendations?

Comment: MySql, sorry (Question Updated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
mysqladmin drop <localdb>
mysqladmin create <localdb>
ssh <host> "/path/to/mysqldump <remotedb>" | /path/to/mysql <localdb>
```